# What is the most distant "object" that can be resolved with current instruments?

Tags: astronomy

**Edit:** I'm specifically interested in thing outside the solar system.

Off hand, this will depend on the definition of "object" and "resolved".

Taking the second term first, let's assume something can be resolved if it is "significantly" wider than the diffraction limit of the instrument looking at it so you can get much more information than would be had from a point source.

As for "object" I'm thinking something where internal interactions via forces other than gravity (edit: and maybe light pressure?)  are non negligible. That excludes black holes (sorry EHT), galaxies or low density gas clouds (even ones accelerated by *external* light pressure), but includes things like rocks, planets, stars, accretion disks (the dense ones around compact objects). (BTW, I'd be open to answers assuming other definitions if they are in common use or give interesting results.)

### Edit 2:

For objects, I'm mostly considering things where gravity has "already mostly done it's thing" and most of the dynamics are driven by other forces, and will continue to to be (unless some outside disruption happens). Relatively large chunks of a objects like star or planet can be modeled to reasonable accuracy considering only the matter, temperatures and pressures present. The fact that gravity is what caused those temperatures and pressures to happen in the first paces no longer has that big an effect. Gravity made stuff happen until something balanced it out and now gravity mostly just keeps things the way they already are.

Another class of thing that doesn't seem like an object to me is *non-bound systems* (e.g. gas jets or the surface of last scattering). They are, or will at some point after things spread out enough become, dominated by gravity so they don't seem like objects to me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_distant_astronomical_objects

Comment: @PM2Ring On a first pass, I'm not seeing anything in that list (further than Uranus) that has been resolved as more than a point source.

Comment: In that case, you're going to have a hard time finding anything that qualifies as a resolvable object that fits your criteria. FWIW, the resolution of the Webb telescope is ~0.1 arc-seconds. https://webb.nasa.gov/content/about/faqs/facts.html

Comment: I think this question needs to be edited for clarity. If accretion disks count, do plasma jets? Some of those are as big and bright as galaxies. Stellar nurseries have clearly nonnegligible internal pressures, but I get the feeling you don't want to count those. You didn't like the surface of last scattering. What makes an object object-y? Maybe science-y definitions aren't well suited to object-y-ness, and common language or analogy are more appropriate.

Comment: @gs: I added some thoughts on object-y-ness; One tl;dr; *non-bound* systems don't seem like objects to me.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the surface of last scattering, which is the place where the the current CMB originates. My understanding is that the surface of last scattering is now about 42 billion light years away.

Comment: I think that would not fall under the definition of "object" I proposed. Rather it would end up being a large group of objects, none of which can be individuality resolved.

Comment: If a star counts then the surface of last scattering should count too. It is the edge of a plasma, just like the surface of a star. The internal non-gravitational interactions are strong as in any plasma

Answer (score 1):

ALMA made interferometry shots of several dust disks in planet forming systems.

EHT imaged hot accretion discs around galactic cores.

Comment: I think both of those kind of tickle the edge of what counts as an object. I suspect both contain clumps that count as objects by most definitions, but maybe not the whole thing. If someone were to "turn off gravity", would the bulk of the mater more or less continue in a straight line? Or would the internal pressure from other forces cause a prolonged "explosion"?